# How do I ensure fast and reliable datasets migration to fiware backend?

Tags: python, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Transferring a very large datasets to `fiware` backend: `SourceDB ->Orion -> Cygnus -> Postgres`. For this I write a python script fetching rows and for each row fetched, send a payload to the Orion.

The script is firing at 150ms(0.15sec) intervals, but to my surprise after about 10 iterations, only two values (the first & last payloads sent) was persisted to the `Postgres` sink. Meaning 80% of the datasets aren't persisted to the sink.

Script:

```
import psycopg2
from time import sleep
from config import config
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
import json

def val_json():
    db = "select to_json(d) from (  select \
        n.noise_data as measurand, \
        n.factor as \"sonometerClass\", \
        to_timestamp(n.seconds) as \"dateObserved\", \
        l.description as name, \
            json_build_object( \
                'coordinates', \
                json_build_array(l.node_lon, l.node_lat) \
            ) as location \
        from noise as n \
            inner join deployment as d on \
                d.deployment_id = n.deployment_id \
            inner join location as l on \
                l.location_id = d.location_id \
        order by n.seconds asc \
    ) as d"
    return db

def main():

    url = 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/002/attrs?options=keyValues'
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", \
               "fiware-service": "urbansense",  \
               "fiware-servicepath": "/basic"}

    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            with conn.cursor(name='my_cursor') as cur:
                cur.itersize = 5000
                cur.execute(val_json())

                for row in tqdm(cur):
                    jsonData = json.dumps(row)
                    if jsonData.startswith('[') and jsonData.endswith(']'):
                        jsonData = jsonData[1:-1]
                        print()
                        print(jsonData)
                    requests.post(url, data= jsonData, headers=headers)
                    sleep(0.15)

                cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

First ten iterations (payloads):

```
$python3 noiselevelObserved.py
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
{"measurand": 64.8, "sonometerClass": 1, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:15+01:00", "name": "Trindade", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.609973, 41.151943]}}
1it [00:00,  1.75it/s]
{"measurand": 58.8, "sonometerClass": 0, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:16+01:00", "name": "Trindade", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.609973, 41.151943]}}
2it [00:00,  2.23it/s]
{"measurand": 56.5, "sonometerClass": 0, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:17+01:00", "name": "Trindade", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.609973, 41.151943]}}
3it [00:00,  2.76it/s]
{"measurand": 61.1, "sonometerClass": 1, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:18+01:00", "name": "Casa da Musica", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.63041, 41.158091]}}
4it [00:01,  3.31it/s]
{"measurand": 108.5, "sonometerClass": 2, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:18+01:00", "name": "Pr. Liberdade Cardosas", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.611119, 41.146023]}}
5it [00:01,  3.86it/s]
{"measurand": 56.5, "sonometerClass": 0, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:18+01:00", "name": "Trindade", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.609973, 41.151943]}}
6it [00:01,  4.35it/s]
{"measurand": 59.9, "sonometerClass": 1, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:19+01:00", "name": "Casa da Musica", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.63041, 41.158091]}}
7it [00:01,  4.78it/s]
{"measurand": 97.2, "sonometerClass": 2, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:19+01:00", "name": "D. Manuel II", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.625192, 41.148558]}}
8it [00:01,  5.12it/s]
{"measurand": 108.6, "sonometerClass": 2, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:19+01:00", "name": "Pr. Liberdade Cardosas", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.611119, 41.146023]}}
9it [00:01,  5.41it/s]
{"measurand": 57.1, "sonometerClass": 0, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:19+01:00", "name": "Trindade", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.609973, 41.151943]}}
10it [00:02,  5.63it/s]
{"measurand": 53.9, "sonometerClass": 0, "dateObserved": "1970-01-01T01:00:20+01:00", "name": "Casa da Musica", "location": {"coordinates": [-8.63041, 41.158091]}}
```

Reading attributes' values persisted into postgres:

```
postgres=# select  * from urbansense.basic_002_noiselevelobserved ;
  recvtimets   |         recvtime         | fiwareservicepath | entityid |     entitytype     |    attrname    |    attrtype     |               attrvalue               | attrmd
---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | dateObserved   | Text            | 1970-01-01T01:00:15+01:00             | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | latitude       | Number          | 41.1591                               | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | location       | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.609973,41.151943]} | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | longitude      | Number          | -8.65915                              | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | measurand      | Number          | 64.8                                  | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | name           | Text            | Trindade                              | []
 1559045918129 | 2019-05-28T12:18:38.129Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | sonometerClass | Number          | 1                                     | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | dateObserved   | Text            | 1970-01-01T01:00:20+01:00             | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | latitude       | Number          | 41.1591                               | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | location       | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.63041,41.158091]}  | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | longitude      | Number          | -8.65915                              | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | measurand      | Number          | 53.9                                  | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | name           | Text            | Casa da Musica                        | []
 1559045919723 | 2019-05-28T12:18:39.723Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | sonometerClass | Number          | 0                                     | []
(14 rows)
```

Changing the firing rate to 1-second interval doesn't give much improvement, only the 3 result sets (payloads) were persisted (70% lost):

```
postgres=# select  * from urbansense.basic_002_noiselevelobserved ;
  recvtimets   |         recvtime         | fiwareservicepath | entityid |     entitytype     |    attrname    |    attrtype     |               attrvalue               | attrmd
---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | dateObserved   | Text            | 1970-01-01T01:00:15+01:00             | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | latitude       | Number          | 41.1591                               | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | location       | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.609973,41.151943]} | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | longitude      | Number          | -8.65915                              | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | measurand      | Number          | 64.8                                  | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | name           | Text            | Trindade                              | []
 1559046840569 | 2019-05-28T12:34:00.569Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | sonometerClass | Number          | 1                                     | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | dateObserved   | Text            | 1970-01-01T01:00:18+01:00             | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | latitude       | Number          | 41.1591                               | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | location       | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.609973,41.151943]} | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | longitude      | Number          | -8.65915                              | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | measurand      | Number          | 56.5                                  | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | name           | Text            | Trindade                              | []
 1559046845620 | 2019-05-28T12:34:05.620Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | sonometerClass | Number          | 0                                     | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | dateObserved   | Text            | 1970-01-01T01:00:20+01:00             | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | latitude       | Number          | 41.1591                               | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | location       | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.63041,41.158091]}  | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | longitude      | Number          | -8.65915                              | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | measurand      | Number          | 53.9                                  | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | name           | Text            | Casa da Musica                        | []
 1559046850679 | 2019-05-28T12:34:10.679Z | /basic            | 002      | NoiseLevelObserved | sonometerClass | Number          | 0                                     | []
(21 rows)
```

I honestly wouldn't like the firing rate to be up to **a second** because of the data size to be migrated to continue my research. When I first tried it at 1-second interval, I realised is going to take months to complete (maybe 4).

**Question:** Is `Orion CB` (or maybe `Cygnus`) not built to have such power of receiving entity/attributes values at such a rate (150ms/0.15s), Or maybe `Cygnus` isn't *smart enough* to receive notification from `Orion` at such a rate?.

I will appreciate any suggestion to ensure all values are persisted in the shortest time.

Comment: The broker has been tested for throughput and is able to process thousands of requests per second. Of course, never tested with your exact requests. However, I can't imagine that orion is the bottleneck here ... I know very little of Cygnus and if I were you, I'd write a python script to receive the notifications and store in Postgres. With some luck, like this you may be able to use a firing rate of at least hundreds of requests per second ...

Comment: @kzangeli "..I'd write a python script to receive the notifications and store in Postgres..." I don't understand what you mean here. To bypass Cygnus, something like:  `SourceDB ->Orion -> Postgres` ?

Comment: Something like that yes. Might be an option if everything else fails. It is very easy (if you are fluent in Python) to write a script to receive notifications from the broker. You could take a look at the accumulator in the orion repo. We use it for functional tests. I am no Python developer but I imagine it's pretty easy to do the writing to Postgres as well from the same python script.

Comment: @kzangeli Ah, just checking the logs for both Cygnus and the broker. For the broker, the "rate" at which it is firing from the log confirm it receives payloads at incoming rate. For Cygnus however, the there's a little delay (approx 4sec) in the "firing rate". Maybe for database write operations maybe memory issue?

Comment: "Or maybe Cygnus isn't smart enough to receive notification from Orion at such a rate" -> a notification each 0.15s is around 6.66 TPS. This is too small. Both Orion and Cygnus should cope with that. Maybe there is some misconfiguration at Cygnus.

Comment: To confirm my guessing on 6.66 notifications per second... how many entities do your script update in each shot (i.e. how many entities are updated each 0.15 seconds)?

Comment: @fgalan 3 entities for each notification. Does this relate to the `"throttling": 5` value in the Orion-Cygnus subscription I set?

Comment: So actual load is 3 x 6.66 TPS = 20 TPS. Still to small. Yes, `"throttling": 5` could be impacting. I'd recommend modifying your subscription to remove it.

Comment: @fgalan Yes!. That exactly is the cause. It works perfectly now. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the question comments, the solution to this was to remove the `throttling` parameter in the subscription. It makes sense: the throttling makes some notification not being sent (in this particular case, 80% of all the notifications).